# Error in function in do notation

Tags: haskell, logic

i have such function to solve some logic riddle

iloczyny is list with such structure `[((0,0),(0,1),[5,0])...]` 
`[((cords1),(cords2),[Num1,Num2])..]`
   `kandydaci` is list of all possible candidates for my solution and `pola` is list with all possible coordinates in my matrix.
 I wanna choose one candidate and compare it with possible candidate from `iloczyny` then if elements are equal i wanna delete coordinates from `pola` and call function once again.

```
 zbieraj iloczyny kandydaci pola = do
      element <- kandydaci
      (a,b,[c,d]) <- iloczyny
      guard (element == (c_n' [c,d]) && (elem a pola) && (elem b pola))
      nowa <- skasuj a b pola
      rk <- delete element kandydaci -- here is erorr 
      Couldn't match type `Integer' with `[Integer]'
      In the second argument of `zbieraj', namely `rk'
      reszta <- zbieraj iloczyny rk nowa
      return ([a,b] ++ reszta)
```

skasuj looks just like that `skasuj a b lista = delete b (delete a lista)`
i'm not knowledgeable in haskell and cant see whats wrong

Comment: What monad is this supposed to be in? We need the error message, and full example input and output.

Comment: Remember that a monadic bind is not imperative assignment. In this case, you probably want let-bindings in almost every place you're trying to use the monadic bind. You might consider reading up on how monads work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, please write type signatures for your functions. That will produce better error messages, and help readers understand your code better.

However, the error is that

```
nowa <- skasuj a b pola
rk <- delete element kandydaci -- here is erorr
```

use the monadic binding `x <- monadAction`, but they should be ordinary `let` bindings

```
let nowa = skasuj a b pola
    rk = delete element kandydaci
```

A compiling version (with appropriate definition of `c_n'`) of the function is

```
zbieraj iloczyny kandydaci pola = do
      element <- kandydaci
      (a,b,[c,d]) <- iloczyny
      guard (element == (c_n' [c,d]) && (elem a pola) && (elem b pola))
      let nowa = skasuj a b pola
          rk = delete element kandydaci
      reszta <- zbieraj iloczyny rk nowa
      return ([a,b] ++ reszta)
```

Comment: is it possible to mix let and <- ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You can have `let` bindings in a do-block, that's no problem. You can use `<-` in the right hand side of `let` bindings. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: That said, they mean very different things, and generally only one of them is "right," depending on what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: Right. Most of the time, only one will typecheck.

Comment: Probably indentation. I'll paste in an example.

Comment: thanks a lot one more question is it possible to check which guard  statement is false?

Comment: You'd have to rewrite the code for that to add an indication of which condition(s) in the `guard` evaluated to `False` to the result. If it's just for debugging, you can `import Debug.Trace` and add `trace` statements to output that.

Comment: i can see trace print String while evaluating one of statements in guard but how to change it to write String only when value is True

Comment: `guard (condition1 && trace "Condition 1 fulfilled" condition2 && trace "Condition 2 fulfilled" condition3 && trace "Third too" True)` would do that. If you want the results for all conditions regardless of whether one earlier fails, you have to evaluate and trace before the `guard`.

Comment: Thanks alot i'v checked with traces and i see even if all 3 statements are True it does not add it to result list why is it happening ?

Comment: There are points after the `guard` where it can fail. Can you post an example (input, expected output, and the definition of `c_n'`)?

Comment: i'v changed pattern matching i think to much in prolog where (that woudl works (a,b,[c,d]) <- iloczyny changed it to ((a,b),(a',b'),[c,d]) but i dont understand haskell backtracking mechanism so i have alot not needed results

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13254/discussion-between-daniel-fischer-and-whd)